# Disable hover text - Chrome/Edge (Chrome v118.0.5993.89/Edge v118.0.2088.46)

Tags: google-chrome, text, hover, accessibility, microsoft-edge

Is there a way that I can disable the text that appears when I hover over a text on a website like in the image below?

[image]

I have tried everything I can think of both in Windows and in the browsers but it seems to have no effect. I have also tried disabling hover cards but have not been able to fix the issue.

Comment: [Soon](https://github.com/mozilla/wg-decisions/issues/1278) you can use the `::tooltip` CSS pesudo element. (See the [discussion](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/8930) in that issue.) Once that's implemented, you can have a style that is applied to all websites you visit via something like a Stylus plugin (for [chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne) and [firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/)). You could set `display:none` for the tooltip to prevent it from appearing. But it's not available yet :-(

Comment: @slugolicious I believe Tomas is asking as a browser user, not as a site author, is that right, Tomas? Also, would you mind explaining how that is helping accessibility for you?

Comment: @Andy That’s how I was responding, as a browser user. I didn’t say anything about changing the HTML for the page. If the `::tooltip` CSS pseudo element gets implemented, then as a browser user, I can have a custom CSS that is applied to any page I visit. I do that now to test my focus location for all websites. (Noting that my custom focus indicator prevents me from testing WCAG 2.4.7)

Comment: @Andy, "*would you mind explaining how that is helping accessibility for you*", I'm not sure what question that is addressing.  What is the **"that"** that you are referring to?  The custom CSS?

Comment: Sorry that wasn’t clear. I was asking Tomas how disabling tooltips for title attributes helps them for accessibility.

Comment: @Andy - In short it is not an issue that bugs me but a colleague of mine finds it really annoying and she is not disabled in any shape or form and thus does not require that the same text shown in on the webpage also shows when hovering.